# Python recursion doesn't yield desired result

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to find the length of the string with out using the inbuilt `len()` function. Here's my python code:

```py
increment = -1
def lenRecur(aStr):
    '''
    aStr: a string

    returns: int, the length of aStr
    '''
    global increment

    if aStr == '':
        return increment
    else:
        increment += 1
        return lenRecur (aStr[increment:])
print lenRecur ("abcdefq")
```

The result I am expecting is 7 but what I got was 4.What I realized was when the `increment` became 2, the value pass to the `lenRecur (aStr[increment:])` was `"defq"`. Which means `aStr[2:]` is evaluated as `"defq"` instead of `"cdefq"`.

Why this is happening?

Comment: That is because you are doing 2 deductions in each step - First, increasing the value of increment and second, slicing the string on each iteration , keep control over any one and you will be done .

Comment: increment should not be... well incrementing.

Comment: As a side note I'm not a big fan of using globals inside a recursive function.

Answer (score 3):

Your function should not depend on external variables.

```
def lenRecur(aStr):
    '''
    aStr: a string

    returns: int, the length of aStr
    '''
    if aStr == '':
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + lenRecur(aStr[1:])


print lenRecur("abcdefq")
```

Answer (score 0):

As an other option, you could write this:

```
def lenRecur(aStr):
    return _lenRecur(aStr, 0)

def _lenRecur(aStr, acc):
    if not aStr:
        return acc

    return _lenRecur(aStr[1:], acc+1)
```

A noticed by @gboffi in his answer, it is commonly accepted in Python to use a default argument instead of using of an helper function:

```
def lenRecur(aStr, acc = 0):
    if not aStr:
        return acc

    return lenRecur(aStr[1:], acc+1)
```

The choice of one form or the other will depend how much you want/don't want to allow the called to set the initial accumulator value to something else than `0`.

Anyway, the interesting point here is in using an accumulator as the second parameter. That way, you have proper [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization). Unfortunately, this is not properly optimized by Python. But this is a good habit as many other languages have such optimization. And this will be a required skill if you switch someday to functional programing language.

Answer (score 0):

A common idiom is to use a default argument:

```
>>> def l(s, c=0): return l(s[1:], c+1) if s else c
```

This kind of solution works with anything that can be *sliced*

```
>>> l('pip')
3
>>> l([1,2,3])
3
>>> l('')
0
>>> l([])
0
>>>
```